# How to write tests for spree controller decorator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, spree

I'd like to modify some things in the controller and test them using rspec. I want to create `new` action for `Spree::ProductsController`. This is what I've tried

```
routes.rb

resources :products

prodcuts_controller_decorator.rb

Spree::ProductsController.class_eval do
  before_filter :authenticate_spree_user!, :except => [:show, :index]


  def new
    @product = current_user.products.build
  end

end

products_controller_spec.rb

require 'spec_helper'
describe Spree::ProductsController do
  let(:user) {create(:user)}

    before(:each) do
      Spree::Core::Engine.routes
      BigPlanet::Application.routes
      controller.stub :spree_current_user => user
    end

    it "render new template" do
      get :new
      response.should render_template(:new)
    end

  end
end
```

But its using original `Spree::Controller` and gives

```
Failure/Error: get :new
ActionController::RoutingError:
No route matches {:controller=>"spree/products", :action=>"new"}
```

If anyone can shove me in the right direction then it'd great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try changing your describe from

```
describe Spree::ProductsControllerDecorator do
```

to

```
describe Spree::ProductsController do
```

RSpec infers a lot of stuff from the class being described.  You'll also want to add the following to the rspec file:

```
before(:each) { @routes = Spree::Core::Engine.routes }
```

This will manually set the routes in RSpec to include the Spree routes.  Since the route to spree/products_controller#new is not defined in your application (but in Spree instead) you'll have to manually override your routes like this.

Comment: Sorry it was already `Spree::ProductsController`, corrected, but the error persists

Comment: I edited the answer with an additional step that you can use.  We use this in several Spree applications to test decorators with rspec.

Comment: Added the routes as suggested.. still it doesn't identify the routes

Comment: `before(:each) { @routes = Spree::Core::Engine.routes }` adding this line helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

in spec_helper.rb, you'll need to add

```
require 'spree/core/testing_support/controller_requests'
```

then, add

```
config.include Spree::Core::TestingSupport::ControllerRequests, :type => :controller
config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
```

in the

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
```

block

explanation and courtesy of http://rohanmitchell.com/2012/06/writing-controller-tests-for-spree-controllers/

Comment: you can also put this in the rails_helper.rb file